# gtsummary modified cross tab

Tags: r, stat, gtsummary

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2][![i need help in writing gstummary r code to produce  following table output.dummy table shown in above table][2]][2]

i need help in writing gstummary r code to produce  following table output.dummy table shown in above table

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
library(gtsummary)
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

| id | age | sex | country | edu | ln | ivds | n2 | p5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | M | eng | x | 45 | 15 | 40 | 15 |
| 2 | a | M | eng | x | 23 | 26 | 70 | 15 |
| 4 | a | M | eng | x | 26 | 36 | 35 | 40 |
| 5 | b | F | eng | x | 26 | 25 | 36 | 47 |
| 6 | b | F | wal | y | 45 | 45 | 60 | 12 |
| 7 | b | M | wal | y | 60 | 25 | 36 | 15 |
| 8 | c | M | wal | y | 70 | 08 | 25 | 36 |
| 9 | c | F | sco | z | 80 | 25 | 36 | 15 |
| 10 | c | F | sco | z | 90 | 25 | 26 | 39 |

```
structure(list(id = 1:15, age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("eng", "scot", "wale"
    ), class = "factor"), edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
    "y", "z"), class = "factor"), lon = c(45L, 23L, 
    25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 
    69L), is = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
    15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L), n2 = c(40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 
    30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L), p5 = c(15L, 
    20L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 
    25L, 36L)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]
[

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a table similar to what you have above (more similar to the table you had before you updated it). But I think it'll get you most of the way there.

The type of table you're requesting it something that is in the works. In the meantime, you will need to use the `bstfun::tbl_2way_summary()` function. This function exists in another package while we work to make it better before integrating with gtsummary.

```r
library(bstfun) # install with `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun")`
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'

# add a column that is all the same value
trial2 <- trial %>% mutate(constant = TRUE)

# loop over each continuous variable, construct table, then merge them together
tbls_row1 <-
  c("age", "marker", "ttdeath") %>%
  purrr::map(
    ~tbl_2way_summary(data = trial2, row = grade, col = constant, con = all_of(.x),
                      statistic = "{mean} ({sd}) - {min}, {max}") %>%
      modify_header(stat_1 = paste0("**", .x, "**")) 
  ) %>%
  tbl_merge() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)

# repeat for the second row
tbls_row2 <-
  c("age", "marker", "ttdeath") %>%
  purrr::map(
    ~tbl_2way_summary(data = trial2, row = stage, col = constant, con = all_of(.x),
                      statistic = "{mean} ({sd}) - {min}, {max}") %>%
      modify_header(stat_1 = paste0("**", .x, "**")) 
  ) %>%
  tbl_merge() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)

# stack these tables
tbl_stacked <- tbl_stack(list(tbls_row1, tbls_row2))

# lastly, add calculated summary stats for categorical variables, and merge them
tbl_summary_stats <-
  trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    include = c(grade, stage),
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(stat_0 ~ "**n (%)**") %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)

tbl_final <- 
  tbl_merge(list(tbl_summary_stats, tbl_stacked)) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  # column spanning column headers
  modify_spanning_header(
    list(c(stat_1_1_2, stat_1_2_2) ~ "**Group 1**",
         stat_1_3_2 ~ "**Group 2**")
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: very simple question, is there a  way i can download the archive files for bstfun (library(bstfun) # install with `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun")`) . actually i am doing this analysis on a pc where there is no internet. once i have the file , i'll transfer via usb and then i would install via archive /zip folder.

Comment: when i tried to run on different data set. i got following error   tbls_row1 <-
  c("lungfunction", "ivdays" , "no2") %>%
  purrr::map(
    ~tbl_2way_summary(data = trial2, row = age, col = constant, con = all_of(.x),
                      statistic = "{mean} ({sd}) - {min}, {max}") %>%
      modify_header(stat_1 = paste0("**", .x, "**")) 
  ) %>%
  tbl_merge() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `tbl`.
i `tbl = `%>%`(...)`.
x Problem with `mutate()` column `tbl_stats`.
i `tbl_stats = pmap(...)`.
x There was an error assembling the summary statistics for 'lungfunction'
  with summary type 'categorical'.

Comment: There are 2 common sources for this error.
1. You have requested summary statistics meant for continuous
   variables for a variable being as summarized as categorical.
   To change the summary type to continuous, add the argument
  `type = list(lungfunction ~ 'continuous')`
2. One of the functions or statistics from the `statistic=` argument is not valid.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: i updated the question with screenshot of the dataset which giving me error

Comment: Hi Saleem, if you include data (not a screenshot, rather using dput as previously suggested) we can look into it further.

Comment: thanks , i updated the question with dput data.

Comment: I think I see the issue....the summary function wasn't defaulting to continuous summary type when it should have forced a continuous summary type. Please install bstfun with `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun@tbl_2way_summary_type_fix")` and try again

Comment: @ Daniel thank you so much. the fix solved the issue. just wondering  is there a way i can download the archive files for bstfun (library(bstfun) # install with remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun@tbl_2way_summary_type_fix")) . actually i am doing this analysis on a pc where there is no internet. so once i have the file/s , i'll transfer via usb and then i would install via archive /zip folder in r.

Comment: You can download the files directly from GitHub

Comment: thanks. i'll have a go. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ Daniel, thanks. i try to install i get following error  ``` install.packages("C:\bstfun-master\bstfun-master", repos = NULL, type="source") Installing package into ‘\\icnas2.cc.ic.ac.uk/ms9009/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) '\\icnas2.cc.ic.ac.uk\ms9009' CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Warning: invalid package 'Cstfun-mastestfun-master' Error: ERROR: no packages specified Warning in install.packages :  installation of package ‘Cstfun-mastestfun-master’ had non-zero exit status ```

Comment: @ Danie, i installed remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun") on my offline pc from www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/.  but where i get the directory files for remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun@tbl_2way_summary_type_fix") ?

Comment: the bug fix has been merged into the master branch on GitHub, so you can now install directly from https://github.com/ddsjoberg/bstfun without referencing the tbl_2way_summary_type_fix branch.

Comment: @ Daniel, many thanks for merging the the bug fix file. i downlaoded the github.com/ddsjoberg/bstfun but i am having agin same error   ```error problem with mutate ()  col tbl  (assembling the summary statistics for lung function) ```

Comment: i am not sure why i am having same issue. i did remove bstfun and reinstall from updated file but having the issue of assembling summary statistics ). i added the screenshot in question for the error

Comment: @ Daniel, i think my browser was not refreshed at the time of downloading so may b i downloaded old file. let me check at my side first. sorry for  bothering you a lot. thanks for your help

Comment: @ Daniel, sorry no luck. still same error above (asembling the summary statistics for lung function) . screenshot for detial of the error in question.

Comment: @ Daniel, when i try to run rlang:: last_error() it say argument "parent" missing, with no default. i added the screenshot in the question